# Formatting text inside a textarea using php code

Tags: php, html, forms

I have 2 textareas. In the first textarea the user adds text which i need to modify.  In the 2nd textarea the amended text is displayed.

Text that I need to modify has the following format:

```
23.10.15
Text1
Text2
```

I want to put text on the same line.  Between the 2nd and 3rd line I want "-" to appear, like this:

```
23.10.15 Text1 - Text2
```

My code looks like this:

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
 $text = $_POST["text-modify"];
 $text = str_replace('', '', $text);
}
    ?>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />

<textarea name="text-modify" id="text-modify" cols="75" rows="7000">
</textarea>

<textarea name="text-final" id="text-final" cols="75" rows="7000">
<?php echo $text; ?>
</textarea>
</form>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: 7000 rows? What's that all about?

Comment: This seems like a very fragile approach your taking. Especially of you are having a user enter 7000 rows worth of content.  Have you considered having three separate input fields for each of he string components, where if you need multiple sets of data you can just create additional sets of fields for input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explode the text on newlines, pop off the last item, implode with spaces, append the dash and the last piece:

```
$pieces = explode("\n", $text);
$last = array_pop($pieces);
$text = implode(" ", $pieces) . " - " . $last;
```

Even better could be:

```
$text = call_user_func_array('sprintf', array_merge(["%s %s - %s"], explode("\n", $text));
```

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood what was being attempted +1.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your php in the html to make it simpler like such :

```
<textarea name="text-modify" id="text-modify" cols="75" rows="7000"><?php $yourVar ?></textarea>
```

or embed with a string

```
<textarea name="text-modify" id="text-modify" cols="75" rows="7000"><?php echo "Hi I am ". $nameVar ." How are you ? "</textarea>
```